# latexdiff for single character

Tags: latexdiff

I have a document in which many words are corrected in terms of inflection from an original one.
Normally, latexdiff shows the strike and correction for entire word, which makes the difference document longer:

- <strike>question</strike> **questions**
- <strike>asks</strike> **ask**

Can I display their differences by using latexdiff like this?:

- question**s**
- ask<strike>s</strike>

Comment: Currently not possible - there is a feature request for this, but this does not mean that it will be implemented